# Application of Parsevals theorem with Welch method

Tags: python, fft, spectrum

For my project I had to manually code the welch method using the code below. Pretty much it involves finding the spectral density through fft and incorporating windowing and segmenting with overlap.

I need to know if my PSD is correct so I am checking through 2 methods.

1. root of area under the PSD should be the RMS (E[x^2]) and since I have taken away my mean from the data, this should equal the standard deviation of the data
2. Checking if Parseval's theorem holds.

There are two main issues, I am having trouble with. Firstly I am getting a 0Hz peak even after removing the mean at the start. The only way I can remove the 0Hz peak is to take the mean away after I have segmented and multiplied the window. (#### Detrend line ####)

With the peak, point 1 holds up well but without the peak the standard deviation is slightly different from the RMS but thats not a huge concern.

My second issue is that I cant get the Parseval's theorem to hold. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is it necessary for the Parseval's theory to hold? Please let me know if my theory is wrong.

Couple of notes about the code:

- apologies if it isnt efficient coding, I'm still a novice
- dividing the fft by (fs*(win*win).sum()) is something I found through research and also a part of the inbuilt Welch code
- lastly I am using trapezoidal rule for integration
- my FFT energy is a couple of magnitudes smaller (ie E-09)

[PSD with 0Hz peak removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13t32.png)

[PSD with 0Hz peak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA1q0.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import math
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft, fftfreq, rfft
from scipy.signal import detrend, get_window

plt.clf()
plt.close()

###############################################################################

config = '1perc_damping'

dir0 = os.getcwd()
dir1 = dir0+'/'+config
dir2 = dir1+'/Summary files'

data = np.loadtxt(dir1 + '/000deg_500rpm_An_Mxx.dat')

###############################################################################

fs = 625
nperseg = 1024
noverlap = 512
window_meth = 'hanning'


###############################################################################

#detrend
data = data - np.mean(data)


#get windowing method
win = get_window(window_meth, nperseg)

# number of segments
nseg = np.ceil((len(data)-nperseg)/(nperseg-noverlap)) + 1 

total_n = nperseg + (nseg-1)*(nperseg-noverlap)

# padding with zeros
if total_n > len(data):
    n = total_n - len(data)
    padding = np.zeros(np.int(n))
    data = np.concatenate((data,padding))


# fft 

fft_data = 0

for i in range(0,np.int(nseg)):

    start = i*(nperseg-noverlap)

    f_data = np.multiply(data[start:start+nperseg],win) 
    f_data = f_data- np.mean(f_data)   #### Detrend line ### 

    transf = fft(f_data)
    transf_c = (transf*np.conj(transf))/(fs*(win*win).sum())

    fft_data = fft_data + transf_c


Pxx = np.real(fft_data)/(nseg)
fx = fftfreq(nperseg, 1/fs)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(fx[0:512],2*Pxx[0:512])
#plt.plot(fx,Pxx)

plt.figure(2)
x = np.linspace(0,len(data),len(data))
plt.plot(x,data)

#Finding RMS
l = np.int(len(fx)/2 -1)
c = 2
A = 0

for i in range(1,l+1):
    A = A + 0.5*(c*Pxx[i]+c*Pxx[i-1])*(fx[i]-fx[i-1])

RMS = np.sqrt(A)

# Checking Parseval's theorem
data_energy = 0
FFT_energy = 0

for i in range(1,l+1):
    FFT_energy = FFT_energy + 0.5*(np.power(c*Pxx[i],2)+np.power(c*Pxx[i-1],2))*(fx[i]-fx[i-1])

for i in range(1,len(data)):
    data_energy = data_energy + 0.5*(np.power(abs(data[][1][i]),2)+np.power(abs(data[i-1]),2))*(i-(i-1))*(1/625)
```

Comment: Should this be on the https://math.stackexchange.com/, or https://stats.stackexchange.com/ exchange?

Comment: Yeah, this is less about coding issues, and more about expected results from mathematical algorithms. You'll probably get more traction over on one of those math related SEs.

Comment: See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51600/application-of-parsevals-theorem-with-welch-method

Comment: Could please provide the input data, or a link to it?  Also, to save our time in answering your question, could you please strip your example to the minimal code that demonstrates the problem?   (For example, we should not have to take time to reproduce your directory structure).  Thank you.